# returning the closest locations from a database with multiple locations in database

Tags: mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

Hello I am trying to return the closest locations in radius of 100 meters.
The input in the formula should return the closest locations near 100 meters but instead returns the same distance.

```
CREATE TABLE locations (lat decimal, lng decimal);
INSERT INTO locations (lat, lng) VALUES (47.0642512, 15.4696701),(47.0642630, 15.4696744) ;


WITH dt AS
(SELECT (
          ((acos(sin((47.0722487 * pi() / 180)) * sin((lat * pi() / 180)) + cos((47.0722487 * pi() / 180)) * cos((lat * pi() / 180)) * cos(((15.4477908 - lng) * pi() / 180)))) * 180 / pi()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
        ) AS distance
        FROM locations)
        
 SELECT * FROM dt WHERE distance <= 100;



https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3SpLAoG55wrEdnCisvYbrK/3
```

Is where I run it

Could someone help me out ?

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use st_distance_sphere
that is quite simple,

the other dinstance are to great for fit your limit for 100 meters.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE locations (lat double precision, lng double precision);
INSERT INTO locations (lat, lng) VALUES (49.227747, -122.994726)
,(47.0642512, 15.4696701)
,(47.0642630, 15.4696744);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
 * 
 FROM 
 locations 
 WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(-122.995842,49.227439  ), POINT( lng ,lat ))  <= 100;

| lat       | lng         |
| --------- | ----------- |
| 49.227747 | -122.994726 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
st_distance_sphere(POINT(-122.995842,49.227439  ), POINT( lng ,lat ))
 FROM 
 locations ;

| st_distance_sphere(POINT(-122.995842,49.227439  ), POINT( lng ,lat )) |
| --------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 87.97942831882659                                                     |
| 8584909.968344273                                                     |
| 8584908.937326042  

                                               |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3SpLAoG55wrEdnCisvYbrK/7)

Comment: I get a syntax error when i execute it on DB Fiddle